# Cannot find implementation for Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am currently working on a Compose application and would like to utilize Room for database management.

Despite my attempts to implement Room, I consistently encounter the following error:

Cannot find implementation for com.example.MyApp.repository.MyDatabase. MyDatabase_Impl does not exist

I believe my entity and Dao classes are properly defined (they are not overly complex).

Here's the code for my database:

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [ObjectModel::class, UserModel::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MyDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile
        private var instance: MyDatabase? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): MyDatabase{
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

       
        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): MyDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                MyDatabase::class.java,
                MY_DATABASE_NAME
            )
                .build()
        }
    }

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun objectDao(): ObjectDao
}
```

I try several things but when I try to create the database I have the issue

this is my gradle file :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.my_app"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.my_app"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4")

    //Default kotlin
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")

    //Compose
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    //Test
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))

    //koin
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:3.5.0")

    //livedata
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")

    //datetime
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.1")

    //navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5")

    //Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.0")
}
```

thanks for your help

I try other implementation of database but none work

I try ksp cause some guy have the same issue but I can't make it work I always have a another Issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use Kotlin as language for the Database, apply Kotlin (not Java) annotation processor in the build script:

```
plugins {
  ...
  kotlin("kapt")
}

implementations {
...
    //Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.0")
}
```

Comment: and i suggest migrating it to ksp -> https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp